# DI Unity AssemlyInformation.Title ModuleAttribute.ModuleName and load module on demand/from directory

Tags: c#, unity-container, prism

i started to work with prism + unity DI. I have two problems and questions until now.

**1. Problem/Question**

I would like to use the AssemblyInformation Title as ModuleAttribute.ModelName.

**Problem:**
This doesnt work:

*`[Module(ModuleName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName).Name)]`*

This works well.

*`[Module(ModuleName ="Module1")]`*

**Question:**

Is there any possibility to use AssemblyInformation.Title as ModuleAttribute.Modulename?

**2. Problem/Question**

I would like to load on demand from Directory my Modules, but only modules which has a special prefix in the module name.

**Problem:**

If I check my ModuleCatalog, then is still empty before I initialze the modules.

**Question:**

Is it possible to check before module init the name of the module, because I do not want to exeute the method Initialize() inide of the Module.

**My Bootstrapper:**

```
    protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
            {
                return new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
            }

            protected override void ConfigureContainer()
            {
                base.ConfigureContainer();
            }

            protected override void InitializeModules()
            {
                ModuleCatalog moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog) this.ModuleCatalog;
// Here I would like to discover my modules with special modulename prefix. 
//If the prefix is not found, then I dont want to init the module.

                try
                {
                    base.InitializeModules();
                }
                catch (DuplicateModuleException e)
                {
                }
}
```

**Module:**

```
    [Module(ModuleName = "MyPrefix-Module1")]
        public class PrismModule1Module : IModule
        {
            IRegionManager _regionManager;

            public PrismModule1Module(IRegionManager regionManager)
            {
                _regionManager = regionManager;
            }

            public void Initialize()
            {
               Debug.WriteLine("Module init");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no such built-in functionality and cannot be because in general module is a class (implementing IModule interface) and an assembly may contain several modules.

This is achievable, however, by overriding the default implementation.

2. You need to mark modules as loaded on-demand.  You *need* to initialize the catalog so that module information has been read (about on-demand loading).  Then you may query module information and actually load the modules.

Comment: Based on your answer I found a blog to load modules based on new attribute. I guess I'm able  to adapt this for my need.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at https://prismextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SmartDirectoryModuleCatalog&referringTitle=Home (while codeplex is still there...), this catalog allows you to specify a search pattern for modules to load (like "Modules\MyPrefix*.dll")

Comment: Perfect this helps a lot to create my own implementation.